# keydown event en php?

Tags: php, javascript

este el contexto. voy a cargar un archivo de texto en php, y una vez cargado, quiero mostrar en pantalla una linea del fichero de texto cada vez que presione la tecla "s". sé de javascript y sé normalmente como funciona el evento keydown, pero me confundo en la integración desde la parte de php que es la encargada de procesar el fichero. Alguien que me aclare como puedo hacerlo por favor. Gracias

Mi página seria así. tendría un input file para seleccionar un archivo de texto.txt, un botón de envió. Luego se mostraria la primera linea del fichero de texto, luego presionaria la tecla "s" y me mostraria la siguiente linea, y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: ¿Qué estructura tiene tu o tus archivos de PHP que procesan el  archivo de texto y lo muestran en pantalla?

Comment: Suponiendo que va de linea en linea el archivo como dices, podrías cargar todo el contenido de archivo en un array con una liean por posición de array, siendo el array una variable en javascript.
Ahora mismo no estoy seguro de si se podría hacer sin ajax, pero con ajax se puede. Luego despues de haber cargado el array la primera vez que pulsas el resto seria ir leyendo del array a partir de la primera posicion del array leída.

Comment: Agregaré más detalles..

Comment: @Lorthas gracias, podrias ser más especifico? cargo el archivo con php? luego paso el contenido a javascript? no sé como asignar un valor desde php a javascript.. :(

Comment: @yavg te deje una respuesta saludos.

Comment: Ahora te dejo una respuesta en código con test y todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del body, prueba esto:
No hace falta Ajax para este caso, aunque el código queda algo enremezclado.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivo" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

     <?php
    $ultimo_archivo;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'])) {
            $ultimo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $ultimo_archivo);
            $lineas_archivo = file($ultimo_archivo);
                ?>
                    <script>
                        let cont = 0; // Pone el contador a 0;
                        const lineas = <?php echo json_encode($lineas_archivo); ?>;

                        <?php
                        foreach($lineas_archivo as $k => &$l) {
                            if($k != count($lineas_archivo)-1) {
                                $l = str_replace("\r\n", " S \r\n", $l);
                            }
                            else{                                   
                                $l = str_replace($l, $l." S", $l);
                            }
                        }

                        fopen($ultimo_archivo, "w+");
                        file_put_contents($ultimo_archivo, implode("", $lineas_archivo));

                        ?>

                        //Añade la primera linea
                        document.body.append(lineas[cont++]);

                        //Añade un evento cuando se pulse la letra S
                        addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
                            if(event.key === "s" || event.key === "S") {
                                if(cont <= lineas.length-1) {
                                    //Agrega la siguiente linea e incrementa el contador

                                    //Modifica la linea y agrega una S al final
                                    linea_actual = lineas[cont++];
                                    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";

                                    document.body.append(linea_actual);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    </script>
                <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muy completa tu respuesta!, casi hecho lo que necesito, aunque te confiezo que mi idea era pensar un poco para posteriormente hacerlo, mi fuerte es angular, lo que debía documentarme más era en la parte de php, pero me has mostrado el camino y algunas dudas dudas que tenia. Solo quiero saber  una última cosa, Cómo puedo modificar la linea actual, quiero poner la letra "s" al final de cada linea en el archivo de texto. Ah! y porque usas esta linea: echo json_encode(file($ultimo_archivo)) por qué conviertes a un .json? no bastaria con leer el string de cada linea?

Comment: En este caso habia hecho que se eliminara el archivo despues de leerlo y guardar cada linea en una posición de un array.
@yavg Si quieres conservar el archivo borra la linea donde está la función "unlink".
Quieres añadir la S al final de cada linea del propio archivo y no borrarlo o quieres escribir la S al leer las lineas en el navegador?

Comment: Exacto, en el archivo de texto que tengo cargado, quiero poner al final la S,el resto lo acomodo a mis necesidades, y con esto json_encode lo conviertes en un array?

Comment: @yavg json_encode te codifica un array de php para el formato JSON y como javascript usa el formao json para sus objetos le resulta válido.
Voy a intentar modificar la respuesta para lo que dices.

Comment: te agradezco mucho, pero creo que no es conveniente convertirlo a JSON, se puede solo convertir a un array? cargaré archivos de texto gigantes..

Comment: No estoy seguro, si son archivos gigantes puede que por este procedimiento tengas problemas.Yo hace tiempo tuve un problema a la hora de cargar un json demasiado grande a través de ajax.

Comment: por eso te pregunto si hay un camino para volver una array en lugar de json, creeria que es menos costoso tratar todo como un array que como un JSON

Comment: @yavg he modificado el codigo para lo del archivo.
Voy a asegurarme de que es un array y no un json.

Comment: @yavg Es un Array. Y si no me crees haz un console_log(lineas); Te pone que es un array y te pone con [].
Si aun no me crees haz alert(Array.isArray(lineas)); Y te deberia de decir true (verdadero)
Compara a crear un objeto vacio con {} y haz lo mismo y verás que el resultado es distinto.

Comment: muchas gracias por tan completa respuesta, no creí que tratar de hacer lo que quiero me llevaria tantos dolores de cabeza, asi que recaigo en una ayuda más por favor. creo que no me hice entender, yo deseo poner esa S al final de cada linea de texto según el indice en el que estoy. Es decir si he presionado 3 veces S, quiere decir que estoy en el index 2 (cont =2) del fichero, y entonces ahí debería estar la S al final en el fichero, según el indice en el que estoy. He intentado muchas cosas pero sin resultado, incluso con peticion ajax pero creo que no es el mejor camino...

Comment: @yavg intenta con lo que te he dado modificarlo para que haga eso.
Usa str_replace en el fichero cada vez pulsas S o cuando lees la primera linea y quita la S de la ultima linea que leiste y ponla en la siguiente. Pero es un poco ineficiente al final, porque hay que reescribir el fichero para modificar una sola linea aunque tengas que modificar solo 2 posiciones del array y puedas escribir todas las posiciones de golpe.
Pero estaría bien que alguien mas experimentado aportara algo a estetema.

Comment: esta manera de programa mezclando php html y javascript esta fuera de las normas de programación y es un problema a la hora de dar mantenimiento: Documentación es español http://phpdevenezuela.github.io/php-the-right-way/#guia-de-estilo-del-codigo

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Ya imagino, pero es para que se haga una idea de como se pueden hacer las diferentes cosas.
Lo ideal es que separe el código.
Pero bueno, para no confundr, borro la respuesta y ya.

Comment: no la borres mejor separa el código por que es correcto, pero trata de darle el ejemplo respondiendo tambien a un standar para que se acostumbre a la buenas técnicas de programación.

Comment: @Lorthas el código esta funcional y lo estoy adaptando para hacerlo con una petición Ajax, veo un problema en tu código, y es que no cambia la última linea str_replace("\r\n", " S\r\n", $l)

Comment: @yavg Lo he arreglado apra que printe en todas las lineas la S.
Pero debería adaptar la solución a una más limpia usando Ajax, Además de esa manera se podría hacer como planteas y poder pasar la información del atecla que se pulsado para que se escriba en el archivo la letra pulsada en lugar de escribir una letra fija.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Mi duda es si en el Ajax sería mejor pasar el array ya modificado cada vez que se pulsa una tecla y reescribir el fichero entero o empezar con el fichero vacío e ir escribiendo linea a linea cada vez que se pulsa una tecla. La segunda opción parece la más eficiente, pero nos e si es lo que quiere exactamente Yavg

Comment: tecnológicamente lo mejor es que hagas todas las modificaciones del lado del cliente y por ultimo actualices el fichero usando una sola petición para el update.

Answer (score 2):

**Logica:**
primero que nada, lo que quieres hacer se hace en `javascript` o `jquery`, la manera mas correcta es por `ajax`, en tal caso cuando subes y procesas el archivo normalmente el php tendrá una respuesta de ok termine ... en ese caso lo que puedes hacer es leer el archivo de texto y imprimirlo con un `echo`, como la petición fue hecha mediana `ajax` este tendrá un `callback` o retorno de datos de parte del php, se le llama `response` bueno toma el response y escribelo en un textarea oculto: `<textarea name="hide" style="display:none;"></textarea>` juego de esto haces un javascript que con `keydown s` navegue las lineas del textarea.

ya que de lado del php no existe el keydown, recuerda que php corre de lado del servidor y el evento keydown ocurre de lado del cliente. saludos.

**Peticiones:**

trabajar de esta manera te ayudara mucho ya que solo tienes que hacer una petición por ajax la misma donde subes el archivo hace todo y el response es el resultado, esto equivale a una sola petición.

luego cada vez que presiones la 's' no hará petición por que el texto esta ya en el textarea que rellenaste en la respuesta. y el recorrido por linea lo puedes hacer con una funcion en jquey/javascript esto no genera peticiones al servidor.

en tal caso no he podido darte un código como respuesta ya que no has colocado ningún avance de tu código. cuando tengas algo mas concreto verificare si tengo tiempo para darte una mejor respuesta. saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no he puesto código porque tengo la lógica, pero hacer eso implicaria hacer n peticiones por n cantidad de veces que se presione la tecla, no?

Comment: nooooo. te actualizo ese tema